# Prevent show status bar on ImageView click

Tags: android

I have an app that uses an full screen ImageView. I also use the function below to hide the status bar. But when the user click to the image, the status bar show again. How can prevent the status bar appear on user click?

```
public void HideStatusBar()
    {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```

Comment: try to set listener to imageView and in his body call this method to hide again status bar?

Comment: you should use this function in your image's `setOnClickListener` method

Comment: It partially works. On the first click the status bar appear and the function OnClick() is not called. The function is only called on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

some like this ?

```
yourImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HideStatusBar();
            }
        });
```

hope this to help you for your  case ... :)

Comment: Kristiyan, It partially works. On the first click the status bar appear and the function OnClick() is not called. The function is only called on the second click.